# MySQL Workbench: stored procedures and function are not visible

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, stored-functions

I have created several stored procedures and functions. I can work with them in Schema Inspector (see left side of pic.), but I don't see them in Schema's Ierarchic Tree in Navigator(see upper right side of picture), so I can't export them when I run Management - Data Export.
How can I  make them visible in Navigator?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a little refresh icon on the same line as the SCHEMA heading. Does clicking this help to get all functions? Alternatively simply restarting WB should show the functions in the schema tree.

Comment: Mike, thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work both ways. I suppose, I must reinstall my Workbench but, honestly, I don't have the guts yet.